# ORDER BY Last Message into the First Message

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table, which contain a `message` and `send_date` when I try to Order that by `send_date` it will show the **Last Message** into the first row! Now I want to the **Last Message** display into the Last row.

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
WHERE to_id=3 AND from_id=4 OR to_id=4 AND from_id=3 
ORDER BY `chat`.`send_date` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

[image]

Comment: do `Order by send_date ASC`

Comment: We use DESC (descending) and ASC (Ascending) in ORDER BY clause for this reason :)

Comment: not work: SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to_id=3 AND from_id=4 OR to_id=4 AND from_id=3 ORDER BY `chat`.`send_date` ASC LIMIT 5
the other messages will displayed

Comment: instead of requiring to do multiple order by - you should handle that in your application code

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a subquery and order the result a second time

```
select * from
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM chat 
    WHERE to_id=3 AND from_id=4 OR to_id=4 AND from_id=3 
    ORDER BY `chat`.`send_date` DESC
    LIMIT 5
) tmp 
order by send_date asc
```